# Why I get 404 error in spring boot post request using Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I user spring boot to create an integral calculator. I got a strange 404 error while I try to handle post request.
Here is my controller class that should handle my request. It's test version so doesn't mind that param function doesn't use(if I understand correctly, this should not affect my error).

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    private final CalculatorService calculatorService;

    public MainController(WebCalculatorService calculatorService) {
        this.calculatorService = calculatorService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/calculate")
    public String calculate(Model model, @RequestParam("function") String function, @RequestParam("numFrom") double numFrom,
                          @RequestParam("numTo") double numTo, @RequestParam("step") double step,
                          RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        double rectangleResult = calculatorService.integrateRectangleMethod(numFrom, numTo, step, x -> Math.pow(x, 2));
        double trapezoidalResult = calculatorService.integrateRectangleMethod(numFrom, numTo, step, x -> Math.pow(x, 2));

        model.addAttribute("rectangleResult", rectangleResult);
        model.addAttribute("trapezoidalResult", trapezoidalResult);

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("rectangleResult", rectangleResult);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("trapezoidalResult", trapezoidalResult);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Here is my html page using Thymeleaf with post form for my params to solve equations.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<header>Integral Calculator</header>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>
    <title>Integral Calculator</title>
    <link href="/static/main.css" th:href="@{/main.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <section class="container">

        <form method="POST" th:action="@{/calculate}">

            <label><span class="label-text">Enter integrand f(x): </span><input class="input-cb" type="text"
                                                                                name="function"></label>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Enter range:</legend>
                <label><span class="label-text">From: </span><input class="input-range-from" type="number"
                                                                    name="numFrom"></label>
                <label><span class="label-text">To: </span><input class="input-range-to" type="number" name="numTo"></label>
            </fieldset>
            <label><span class="label-text">Enter step: </span><input class="input-step" type="number" value="0.01"
                                                                      step="0.1" min="0" name="step"></label>
            <p class="error-message is-hidden"></p>

            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="value" class="link-button">Calculate</button>
        </form>

        <div class="results is-hidden">
            <p class="result">Results:</p>
            <p class="result-rect">${rectangleResult}</p> <br/>
            <p class="result-trap">${trapezoidalResult}</p> <br/>

        </div>

    </section>
    <section class="chart-container">
        <p class="chart-info is-hidden">The chart is only available for real number results</p>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </section>
</div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/6.0.2/math.js"></script>
</html>
```

After I push my button calculate a get 404 error, that here's what it looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRMl1.png)

with path like: http://localhost:8080/calculate

I have already tried changing the paths, change my form in the html page, but it did not help, honestly do not understand what I have here error, please help and thanks in advance

Comment: this doesnt make any sense, the url you provided works on my computer for the provided Spring endpoints, both with `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping` so I don't know what it is - clearly you are doing something wrong but based on the information you have provided so far it should work and works on my computer

Comment: hmm, could there be an error in my pom.xml or application.properties?

Comment: no it really must be as simple as you navigating to an endpoint that is not defined. That is what 404 means. If you are using intellij ultimate you can go to View -> Tool Windows -> Endpoints and see a list of all endpoints available

Comment: I checked as you said my endpoints and all is correct. I tried again to change from `@GetMapping` to `@PostMapping` with ModelParam and I can see in MainController my post path /calculate

Comment: can you use inspect option in your browser to see to which url your form's action is pointing to?

Comment: Here is tag form in which placed button
<form action="/calculate" method="post"> </form>
So the path should be correct to my endpoint

`

Comment: sorry cant help you, this weird behavior is unfortunately not reproduceable

Comment: Depending on your browser, the browser will not change the method on redirect. It could be that you are executing a **POST** on **/** where your tomcat has no route defined.

Comment: I solve this problem by move Spring boot main class out from other packages, thank you a lot for your advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem just recompiled my project and after that this stupid error was gone. But thanks everyone for yours answers.